# Зачем буферизировать при подключении шаблона?

Tags: шаблоны

Зачем буферизировать при подключении шаблона? Простите за "тупой" вопрос, просто не пойму этот момент. А если не делать буферизацию, будет все плохо?) Спасибо заранее за ответ!

```
class View
{
    function render($tpl, $data)
    {
        extract($data);

        ob_start();
            include $tpl;
        return ob_get_clean();
    }
}
```

Comment: @vinnie

> Зачем буферизировать при подключении шаблона?

Чтобы сохранить полученный вывод в переменную и впоследствии обработать его.

> А если не делать буферизацию, будет все плохо?

Нет, но возможность работы с готовым контентом отпадет. Например, нельзя будет отдельно срендерить view и затем вставить его в layout.

Comment: Как и где лучше определять layout?

Comment: @vinnie, вы уверены, что он вам вообще нужен на этом этапе? В Yii это просто такой же view-файл, просто сначала рендерится view, подставляется в переменную $content, а затем рендерится layout, в котором предполагается вывод переменной $content. Валяются лейауты там же, где и view.

Comment: Я имею ввиду можно ж и без буферизации присвоить переменной вывод
    class View
    {
        function render($tpl, $data)
        {
            extract($data);
            $content = include $tpl;
     
        }
    }

Comment: @vinnie, только если в файле стоит `return 'большая-большая строка';`. Если в файле что-то выводится, то это не попадет в переменную.

Comment: блин... не понятно(((